# Who is this cat on Hunter X Hunter volume 32's cover?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I have watched the anime version of *Hunter x Hunter* but I couldn't remember where or when I have seen this cat, who is this cat? Does the cat ever appear in the manga/anime ver. ?

[image: Jin & Cat]

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I swear that cat might be a Togashi self-portrait. Take off his glasses, give him a grin and orange facial hair ...

Answer (score 3):

Particularly just a nameless cat.

This seems to follow the previous "character & animal" volume cover series on volume 17-19:

- Volume 17: Killua (wolf)

  [image: Killua & Wolf]
- Volume 18: Kurapika (owl)

  [image: Kurapika & Owl]
- Volume 19: Leorio (goldfish)

  [image: Leorio & Goldfish]

Comment: Is this related to volume 33 which has kurapika ilustration with a dolphin?

Comment: But there was kurapika with an owl in vol 18...

Comment: @Gagantous it could be related, it could be not. It could also probably not mean anything and just a random "character & animal"... **edit**: on the second thought, there are other animals other than dolphin on volume 33's, probably it's unrelated.

Comment: what's the reason of this ""character & animal"" on hxh cover ?